# Why it never reaches the else part?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, dom

I'm new, so sorry for the bad code. It works, but it somehow never reaches the else part, regardless of what is the condition. I've tried multiple things, but nothing seems to work. Why?

```js
let lock = true;

let screen = document.querySelector("#screen p");
let one = document.querySelector("#one");
let two = document.querySelector("#two");
let three = document.querySelector("#three");
let four = document.querySelector("#four");
let five = document.querySelector("#five");
let six = document.querySelector("#six");
let seven = document.querySelector("#seven");
let eight = document.querySelector("#eight");
let nine = document.querySelector("#nine");
let zero = document.querySelector("#zero");
let division = document.querySelector("#division");
let multiplication = document.querySelector("#multiplication");
let plus = document.querySelector("#plus");
let minus = document.querySelector("#minus");
let clear = document.querySelector("#clear");
let equal = document.querySelector("#equal");

let arr = [one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, zero];
let arr2 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"];
let fNum = "";

if (lock === true) {
  plus.addEventListener("click", function() {
    fNum += "+";
    screen.innerText += "+";
    lock = false;
  });
  minus.addEventListener("click", function() {
    fNum += "-";
    screen.innerText += "-";
    lock = false;
  });
  multiplication.addEventListener("click", function() {
    fNum += "*";
    screen.innerText += "*";
    lock = false;
  });
  division.addEventListener("click", function() {
    fNum += "/";
    screen.innerText += "/";
    lock = false;
  });

  clear.addEventListener("click", function() {
    screen.innerText = "";
    fNum = "";
  });

  for (let i in arr) {
    arr[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      fNum += arr2[i];
      screen.innerText += arr2[i];
    });
  }
} else {
  let answer = "This part right here";
}
```

Comment: Is a part/any of this code wrapped in a function? If not, then it is probably called only once and for that one time lock is true.

Comment: The `else` can only possibly run when the script is first loaded, but it won't because `lock` is `true`. Setting `lock` to `false` in the "click" handlers is fine, but from the code you posted it won't have any effect.

Comment: Please click [edit] then scroll down and click edit above snippet and add relevant HTML and CSS. Your code needs to be inside a click event handler. I suggest you use delegation. If you add the HTML, I will help you with this

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a wrapping event listener like this

```js
const screen = document.querySelector("#screen p");

const arr = [one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, zero];
const arr2 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"];


let fNum = "";
document.getElementById("calculator").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  const val = tgt.value;
  if (tgt.id === "clear") {
    screen.innerText = "";
    fNum = "";
    return
  }
  if (tgt.id==="division") {
    fNum += "/";
    screen.innerText += "/";
  }
  // ...
})
```